# Server error when using debugger to view objects in google app script

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, google-apps-script, server-error

I am trying to use the google app script debugger to help me walk through my code. When I try to expand an object (see debugger picture below) to see what it contains I get this error: 
[image: Server error]

[image]

A long-winded workaround that I've used is to export the object to a .json file in my Drive and then download and open to see the structure and what's contained. I'd love some other way besides that.

I've seen this happen before, but I'm not sure if it's an error on my part, something google app script doesn't allow you to do, or something else. Anyone have any idea or resources I could look at? Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code to try to reproduce this?